# How to correctly import a constant in VHDL

Tags: import, constants, vhdl, modelsim

In our VHDL project we've got a .vhdl file containing constants, and I'm not sure how to access them correctly. The following line can be found in a package "packages" and the file containing all the constants is called parameters.vhdl

```
constant param_ticks_per_second : unsigned(31 downto 0) := to_unsigned(12500000, 32);
```

then in a package called "entities" there's a file defining the black box of the entity called clock_divider-entity.vhdl containing this line

```
generic(ticks_per_second : unsigned(31 downto 0));
```

Finally, there's the file defining the architecture of the entity in which i'd like to write the following line of code

```
constant c_reload_value : ticks_per_second := param_ticks_per_second;
```

how can I import param_ticks_per_second from the file with the constants into the architecture file? My modelsim project is called tp78, and I've tried the following syntax

```
library tp78;
use tp78.parameters.all;
```

but the compiler generates errors linked to the definition of the constant in the architecture file. Could anyone suggest a solution to this case?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] to avoid misunderstandings, including the error message(s).

Comment: What does the error message say? Have you imported std_numeric in the constants package, as you use `unsigned`?